# Why is ANSI printing the code the first time the function is called and printing colours the second time around?

Tags: c, colors, printf

I am trying to change the colour output of my printf statements in a connect 4 game. I have made a function to set the print colour and reset it. It works for most of my code but doesn't work on the first function that is called the first time it is called, but works from there out. The function in question is the first function called in the main program.

I have tried different positioning of the function, positioning it either side of where the function is called and inputting the colour codes directly into the printf function but it always fails the first (and only the first time).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sprint_green();
void sprint_red();
int main_menu ( void ){
    int a = 0;
    char opt [20];
    sprint_red();
    printf("============================\n");
    printf("    Welcome to Connect4!\n");
    printf("============================\n");
    sprint_reset();
    // Continue asking for an option until a valid option (n/l/q) is entered
    while (a == 0)
    {
        sprint_green();
        printf("(N)ew game\n(L)oad game\n(Q)uit");
        sprint_reset();
        fgets(opt, 20, stdin);
    // if 'n', return 1
        if(opt[0] == 'n' || opt[0] == 'N'){
            a = 1;
        }
    // if 'l', return 2
        else if(opt[0] == 'l' || opt[0] == 'L'){
            a = 2;
        }
    // if 'q', return -1
        else if(opt[0] == 'q' || opt[0] == 'Q'){
            a = -1;
            printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
        }
    // if anything else, give error message and ask again..
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid option\n");
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    return(a);
}

int main (void)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        main_menu();
    }
}

void sprint_green()
{
  printf("\033[1;32m");
}

void sprint_red()
{
  printf("\033[1;31m");
}

void sprint_reset()
{
  printf("\033[0m");
}
```

First three printf statements are expected to be printed in red and the next one is to be printed in green. However the first time it is called the print the ANSI colour codes.

```
[1;31m============================
    Welcome to Connect4!
============================
[0m[1;32m(N)ew game
(L)oad game
(Q)uit[0m
```

However, after running the game once and starting again (without closing the terminal) these functions work as expected.

Comment: Code fails to compile, because parts of it are missing. Please remove all parts that are not necessary to demonstrate your problem, that is, create [mcve].

Comment: \ is a reserved character in C strings. To include it in a string, you need to preceed it by another \, so `printf("\\e[1;31m%c\\e[0m", print);`

Comment: @user694733 thanks for your feedback. I have edited it to a compilable version now which reproduces the same error.

Comment: After fixing you code (adding `#include <stdlib.h>` and forward declare `sprint_reset()`) I get proper result. Maybe run `cls` on the beginning of the program?

Comment: On Linux it works, apart from the non-existent `cls`. In a Windows `cmd` window the escape character is printed as a visible character before `cls` is executed, afterwards the escape sequences are processed correct. In a Windows Mingw64 shell window I see a buffering issue, and `cls` doesn't seem to work. The output appears when the program exits, but all colors are correct. The non-portable `cls`doesn't work. After adding a `setvbuf` call with `_IONBF` the output appears immediately. Obviously the result depends on the type of terminal, and the `cmd` window behaves differently after a `cls`.

Comment: thank you @KamilCuk, that fixed it. I do still need the cls after however having another before everything has made it work.

Answer (score 1):

The windows command shell does not start vt100 emulation by default. As @Bodo pointed out in his answer, this can be triggered by running the shell command `cls`. However, technically the shell command need not be `cls` or even a valid command at all. You can trigger it with just an empty `system(" ")` call! This is also portable because it does nothing except start a shell instance momentarily and kill it. So it should work equally fine in Windows or Linux environments.

Code with the fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for system()

void sprint_green();
void sprint_red();
int main_menu ( void ){
    int a = 0;
    char opt [20];
    system(" "); // Trigger ANSI emulation
    sprint_red();
    printf("============================\n");
    printf("    Welcome to Connect4!\n");
    printf("============================\n");
    sprint_reset();
    // Continue asking for an option until a valid option (n/l/q) is entered
    while (a == 0)
    {
        sprint_green();
        printf("(N)ew game\n(L)oad game\n(Q)uit");
        sprint_reset();
        fgets(opt, 20, stdin);
    // if 'n', return 1
        if(opt[0] == 'n' || opt[0] == 'N'){
            a = 1;
        }
    // if 'l', return 2
        else if(opt[0] == 'l' || opt[0] == 'L'){
            a = 2;
        }
    // if 'q', return -1
        else if(opt[0] == 'q' || opt[0] == 'Q'){
            a = -1;
            printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
        }
    // if anything else, give error message and ask again..
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid option\n");
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    return(a);
}

int main (void)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        main_menu();
    }
}

void sprint_green()
{
  printf("\033[1;32m");
}

void sprint_red()
{
  printf("\033[1;31m");
}

void sprint_reset()
{
  printf("\033[0m");
}
```

Comment: I only observed that calling `system("cls");` seems to activate the ANSI emulation. Do you have an explanation why any `system(something);` has the same effect. Is there a documentation anywhere?

Comment: @Bodo Unfortunately I don't know exactly why this works. Years ago, when I was struggling with the same issue, someone suggested `system(" " )` and it worked! Since it solved my problem, I didn't probe further. My best guess is that the command shell switches on ANSI emulation before running **any** shell command. Or it switches on ANSI emulation using `SetConsoleMode()` when called from within an instance of itself.

Comment: @Bodo I tested it just now on a windows 10 machine and it still works! And if that line is commented out, the escape sequences are not detected anymore. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I didn't try this. My only concern is that relying on an undocumented solution might be dangerous because it may change in future or it may depend on other things you are not aware of. That's why a reference to related documentation would be helpful.

Comment: @Bodo I don't see `system("cls")` either in the official MS documentation. This whole behaviour is likely to be an unintended side-effect of something rather than a documented feature. Nevertheless, this is a solution that has been out there and known to work for several years now (despite several windows updates), so I don't find a significant risk on that regard. It is probably the only way to have the exact same code work in both Windows and Linux environments, which I feel is quite nice. So I leave it up to the reader to choose the trade-off he feels comfortable with.

Comment: I don't vote against this solution, I only suggest to search for a reference better than "someone suggested `system(" " )`". You should add the background information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`system("cls");` works, but it clears the screen.
But if you call it only once at startup it seems to fix it for the entire application

Answer (score -1):

According to
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/04/08/c-programming-ansi-escape-codes-windows-macos-linux-terminals/
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences?redirectedfrom=MSDN
the Windows console must be put into an ANSI escape mode to be able to process escape sequences instead of printing them.

Apparently executing the `cls` command seems to do this.

You can set the terminal mode programmatically using `GetConsoleMode()` and `SetConsoleMode()` by setting the flag `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`

Code example copied from the referenced Microsoft page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    // Try some Set Graphics Rendition (SGR) terminal escape sequences
    wprintf(L"\x1b[31mThis text has a red foreground using SGR.31.\r\n");
    wprintf(L"\x1b[1mThis text has a bright (bold) red foreground using SGR.1 to affect the previous color setting.\r\n");
    /* ... more examples removed */

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this solution is for Windows only, but running `system("cls")` is also non-portable.